# Why does my JaveScript Connect 4 function not work as I expect it to?

Tags: javascript, function

```
function checkWin(CheckArray){ 
  for(i = 0; i<CheckArray.length; i++){
    if(CheckArray.includes(CheckArray[i] && CheckArray[i] + width && CheckArray[i] + (2*width) && CheckArray[i] + (3*width)) ||
 CheckArray.includes(CheckArray[i] && CheckArray[i] + 1 && CheckArray[i] + 2 && CheckArray[i]+3) || 
CheckArray.includes(CheckArray[i] &&CheckArray[i] + (width-1) && CheckArray[i]+2*(width+1) && CheckArray[i] + 3*(width-1)) ||  
CheckArray.includes(CheckArray[i] && CheckArray[i] + (width+1) && CheckArray[i] + 2*(width+1) && CheckArray[i] + 3*(width+1))){
      disCurrentPlayer.innerHTML=` Win`;
    }
  }

}
```

My logic: record every step of each player and save it in the array, then check if any element in the list meets the conditions to win the game

here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74342020/edit) to include an example of the `CheckArray` variable passed to your function, as well as the (global?) `width` variable.

Comment: 1. What do you expect it to do? 2. Give us a case that we can run demonstrates that it _doesn't_ do that. 3. Break down long lines over multiple lines.

Comment: There are probably a lot of deficiencies in this. hard to know where to start.

Comment: Not sure that is enough to go off of, but for starters, you may need to use a 2D array, unless you want it to get even more messy. I would also suggest trying to refactor so that your IF condition is easier to read.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question on stackoverflow. This function is to verify that if 4 checkers of the same color are in a row, then the player wins. CheckArray[i] +  (width-1) and CheckArray[i] + (width+1) is for the diagonal row, CheckArray[i]+1 is for horizontal and CheckArray[i]+width  is for horizontal vertical.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I may have been too subtle. You are mixing up `CheckArray[i] + 1` with `CheckArray[i+1]`. They do very different things.

So, if you are using a single dimension array to represent all of the positions on the Connect 4 board, you need each position to have 3 possible values: player 1, player 2 and empty.

but, you seem to be using `.includes` in a way that I don't understand.
`includes` will search the array for a value that matches the value you pass to it. Since you use `&&` in the first test it will pass in one of these:

```
CheckArray[i]
CheckArray[i] + width 
CheckArray[i] + (2*width)
CheckArray[i] + (3*width)
```

Assuming `width` is some positive integer. I don't know what is in CheckArray[i].  Let's say it is `1` because that's a common number people use. For example, if `width`
is 7, the number of columns, the value passed in is `22`, because 1 + 3 * 7 is 22.
Would the value 22 ever be in your array? That seems unlikely.

Continuing on, you make similar mistakes with the rest of the code.

Presumably, you want to test if the values in multiple positions are equal, something like:

`CheckArray[i] && CheckArray[i] === CheckArray[i+width] && CheckArray[i] === CheckArray[i + 2*width] && CheckArray[i] === CheckArray[i + 3*width]`

Continuing on, in this game, you only need to test 1 position, which is the most recent one played. You don't need to search for 4 in a row anywhere, because if it already existed, the game would already be over.

For that latest move, you need to check 16 possible "wins". That is, it can be any position of 4 horizontally, vertically, diagonally positive slope, and diagonally negative slope.  You could write code to test all 16 possibilities, and that might be the best solution for your coding level.

Comment: Thank you. My idea would have been to record every step of every player and store it in a array. Then when four of the numbers in the array met the conditions, the player won. For   example, If the player's first step is the last cell, then 41 will be pushed into the array, keep playing until the array have 41 40 39 38 or 41 41-7  41-14  41-21 the player win. I've also thought about documenting all the winning methods and comparing them. But I think this method is a bit less convenient.

Comment: I see. Did you figure it out? You'd need to call `includes` for each index. Using `&&` inside the `includes` doen't tell you if it includes all of those things. It combines them all to 1 number and only looks for that number.